# Can't write Url Rewrite rule

Tags: iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I have IIS 7.5 and want to rewrite some urls
pattern is:
urls like /img/[TEXT].html should be rewritten to /pages/Default.aspx?file=[TEXT].jpg

I try to do it:

```
            <rule name="My Rule">
                <match url="/jpg/(.+)\.html" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/pages/Default.aspx?file={R:1}.jpg" />
            </rule>
```

but it does not work. Why and how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my problem. This code really works, but checking tool, included to IIS, says that pattern is not matched by unknown reasons!